# Updating excel file in Java with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to update my excel file, but for some reason I get null from cell at second attempt.

```
public class ExcelWriter {


    XSSFSheet sheet;

    public ExcelWriter(List<String> nurses, List<String> therapist)  {


        FileInputStream file;
        try {

            file = new FileInputStream("Schedule.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i=0;i<nurses.size();i++)
            {
                writeToCell(i+1,0,nurses.get(i));
            }

           for (int i=0;i<therapist.size();i++)
            {
                writeToCell(i+10,0,nurses.get(i)); //Getting null here
            }


            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("Schedule.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    private void writeToCell(int row, int col, String string) {

        Cell cell = null;

        XSSFRow sheetrow = sheet.getRow(row);

        cell = sheetrow.getCell(col); //Getting null here
        cell = sheetrow.createCell(col); 
        cell.setCellValue(string);

    }



}
```

Log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.michlind.cheduler.ExcelWriter.writeToCell(ExcelWriter.java:66)
at com.michlind.cheduler.ExcelWriter.<init>(ExcelWriter.java:40)
at com.michlind.cheduler.MainClass$2.actionPerformed(MainClass.java:343)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get `null` at the line before? `sheetrow.getCell(col);` can return null if no cell exists

Comment: I probably get the null before and try to use in the next line, I will update my question. So how cell can not exist? There is huge number of rows and columns in sheet...

Comment: Assuming you have created the sheet by hand, every cell you have not written anything to is treated as `null`. Just check if the cell exists and if not, create it